# How to import generated GD image in FPDF

Tags: php, gd, fpdf

I'm trying to include generated JPEG image in pdf file generated with FPDF.

Already a have the code to generate the image and works perfectly in the browser, but, when I try to insert in pdf with FPDF show an error. "failed to open stream".

```
$pdf = new FPDF ( 'P', 'pt' ,'A4' );
$pdf -> AddPage ();
$pdf -> Image ( __DIR__ . '/pattern.php', 0, 0, 100, 100, 'JPG');
$pdf -> Output ( 'I' );
```

Expected result is the image in pdf file.

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path on the `Image` call?

Comment: Hi @Dave, yes, I did it, and works on a server with domain. but not work on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Hello EI Tito Barte :-

I think so the alternatively please if you could try the below code.

Here, 33.78 is the size of the image :-

$pdf->Image($image1, $pdf->GetX(), $pdf->GetY(), 33.78).

Here, $image1 = "img/products/image1.jpg";

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Man87, but the arguments of the $pdf -> Image () are ok, i don't know where you get the $image value, when my image is generated in PHP with GD and not stored anywhere.

Comment: // Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

The above command will output the image and you
will get the necessary information of the image from 
the above function.

Comment: in the pettern.php file, is already done the output imagejpeg(), the function works perfectly on a server with domain, but not works on localhost.